# What calls count toward the Google Drive Calls Per Second Rate Limit?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Also, is there a way to check what your current QPS limit is?  We are currently experiencing a large number of errors with the following info:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <error>
    <domain>GData</domain>
    <code>rateLimitExceeded</code>
    <internalReason>Rate limit exceeded, lower query rate</internalReason>
    <extendedHelp>Request rate limit exceeded.</extendedHelp>
  </error>
</errors>
```

We have stats around all our drive calls.  As far as I can tell, we should be well under our QPS.

When only counting "drive API" calls (calls made using the drive API) we're at about half of what our QPS limit should be. If you add in calls made to the export links (which are in the format of the old Document List API) we are still below what our limit should be.

I have tried reaching out to google to confirm what our limit is, and whether or not we are are actually going over our QPS (or if there's something else going on) but have not received any reply.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Also, we are using exponential backoff and have implemented it as suggested in the Drive API docs.

Answer (score 0):

In the api console you can see and increase the rate limit per second. Increasing it also means that a bad user could consume the entire quota. If youre making the api calls using a single user's auth is worse than distributing it across each user's own auth token since the limit is per user.

Comment: The API Console only allows you to increase your rate limit per second, per user, not the overall QPS (there is a section for what you want your overall QPS to be when you click "request more")  To ensure this is not an issue with the requests per second per user, I set that limit to 10,000.